# Excel xlsx вытащить картинку

Tags: алгоритм, парсер, excel

Я разобрался с быстрым парсингом xlsx так чтобы память сервер не жрал. Осталось разобраться с картинками, которые лежат на странице ексель по координатам. Все они лежат аккуратно в папочке \xl\media

Как ее найти - создать файл эксель, в нем перетаскиванием переместить из интернета любую картинку.Сохранить файл. переименовать расширение xlsx на zip. Открыть как zip архив.

В распакованном xlsx лежит папка \xl\drawings в ней соответственно файл drawing1.xml в нем соответственно схема расположения картинок на первой вкладке.

на каждую картинку есть свои координаты пример:

```
<a:off x="17722952" y="110423324"/>
<a:ext cx="1555648" cy="2371725"/>
```

как мне понять к какой строчке относится эта картинка - какая в данном случае формула или это надо брать ширину каждого столбца, в моем случае это будет высота каждой строчки и уже смотреть на какую строчку попадает? Если так то придется перебирать весь массив строк столько раз сколько картинок.
Есть идеи?

Вот кусок информации о картинки с id 2

```
<xdr:twoCellAnchor editAs="oneCell">
        <xdr:from>
            <xdr:col>15</xdr:col>
            <xdr:colOff>187427</xdr:colOff>
            <xdr:row>39</xdr:row>
            <xdr:rowOff>123824</xdr:rowOff>
        </xdr:from>
        <xdr:to>
            <xdr:col>15</xdr:col>
            <xdr:colOff>1743075</xdr:colOff>
            <xdr:row>39</xdr:row>
            <xdr:rowOff>2495549</xdr:rowOff>
        </xdr:to>
        <xdr:pic>
            <xdr:nvPicPr>
                <xdr:cNvPr id="2" name="Picture 1" descr="Снегурочка"/>
                <xdr:cNvPicPr>
                    <a:picLocks noChangeAspect="1" noChangeArrowheads="1"/>
                </xdr:cNvPicPr>
            </xdr:nvPicPr>
            <xdr:blipFill>
                <a:blip xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" r:embed="rId1"
                        cstate="print">
                    <a:extLst>
                        <a:ext uri="{28A0092B-C50C-407E-A947-70E740481C1C}">
                            <a14:useLocalDpi xmlns:a14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2010/main" val="0"/>
                        </a:ext>
                    </a:extLst>
                </a:blip>
                <a:srcRect/>
                <a:stretch>
                    <a:fillRect/>
                </a:stretch>
            </xdr:blipFill>
            <xdr:spPr bwMode="auto">
                <a:xfrm>
                    <a:off x="17722952" y="110423324"/>
                    <a:ext cx="1555648" cy="2371725"/>
                </a:xfrm>
                <a:prstGeom prst="rect">
                    <a:avLst/>
                </a:prstGeom>
                <a:noFill/>
                <a:ln>
                    <a:noFill/>
                </a:ln>
                <a:extLst>
                    <a:ext uri="{909E8E84-426E-40DD-AFC4-6F175D3DCCD1}">
                        <a14:hiddenFill xmlns:a14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2010/main">
                            <a:solidFill>
                                <a:srgbClr val="FFFFFF"/>
                            </a:solidFill>
                        </a14:hiddenFill>
                    </a:ext>
                    <a:ext uri="{91240B29-F687-4F45-9708-019B960494DF}">
                        <a14:hiddenLine xmlns:a14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2010/main" w="9525">
                            <a:solidFill>
                                <a:srgbClr val="000000"/>
                            </a:solidFill>
                            <a:miter lim="800000"/>
                            <a:headEnd/>
                            <a:tailEnd/>
                        </a14:hiddenLine>
                    </a:ext>
                </a:extLst>
            </xdr:spPr>
        </xdr:pic>
        <xdr:clientData/>
    </xdr:twoCellAnchor>
```

Каждая строка в excel это товар и как соотнести товар и картинку еще тот вопрос...

Comment: пока только наткнулся на макрос BottomRightCellTopLeftCell - хотелось бы понять эту формулу чтобы перенести на другой язык программирования

Comment: По идее `<xdr:col>15</xdr:col>` `<xdr:row>39</xdr:row>` - это как раз колонка и строка, где находится якорь картинки.

Comment: @insolor спасибо - буду проверять

Comment: @insolor да все верно - у них видимо они начинаются с 0 поэтому <xdr:row>39</xdr:row> это будет 40 строчка